# A question about block regression

Tags: statistics, regression

Assume that a linear model is $y = X\beta + \varepsilon$
then the OLS is $\hat{\beta} = (X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}y$.

Consider the block matrix $X = (X_1,X_2)$ which is 
corresponding to $y = X_1\beta_1 + X_2\beta_2 + \varepsilon$.

Let

$\tilde{\beta_2}(\beta_1) = argmin_{\beta_2}||y-X_1\beta_1-X_2\beta_2||^2$

and

$\tilde{\beta_1} = argmin_{\beta_1} |||y-X_2\tilde{\beta_2}(\beta_1) - X_1\beta_1||^2$

Is it true that

\begin{equation}
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\tilde{\beta_1} \\
\tilde{\beta_2}(\tilde{\beta_1})
\end{array}
\right)
=
\hat{\beta}
\end{equation}

Comment: Use `\operatorname{argmin}` for $\operatorname{argmin}$.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, as long as the combined $X$ matrix has full column rank. Otherwise the solution may not be unique and your argmin formulation may be ill-posed.

Comment: how to prove it?